# Android how to recognize a GS1 DataBar barcode?

Tags: java, android, barcode-scanner

I'm looking for a way to read [GS1 DataBar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GS1_DataBar) style barcodes from an Android app. Has anyone tried that? Are there any open source barcode scanner projects that I can take advantage of to read GS1 barcodes?

Comment: I found paid libs that supports GS1 Barcode:          1)Vision Smart -    https://www.visionsmarts.com/sdk/vs-barcode-reader.html                                     2) Accusoft -                                                                                  https://help.accusoft.com/BarcodeXpressAndroid/v10/html/concepts.html#barcodetypes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

That will scan GS1 codes, but GS1 isn't a bar code format as much as its a format of the number encoded into the barcode.  Processing what those numbers mean is outside zxing's realm.

http://helpdesk.gs1.org/ArticleDetails.aspx?id=d5ac7325-e5cc-496d-b821-c209f4718536

Comment: Thanks for the award.  Just so you know I was able to scan the top code with ZXing on the wikipedia article you attached.  The next code was probably too small.  I couldn't get it to scan.

Comment: GS1 Databar is not supported at all, I tried their library and even its not mention on their official github account.                                                                                        It only supports below formats:   
                                                                                                                                UPC-A, Code 39, QR Code, UPC-E, Code 93, Data Matrix, EAN-8, Code 128,  Aztec, EAN-13, Codabar, PDF 417, UPC/EAN,  Extension 2/5,  ITF, MaxiCode,
RSS-14, RSS-Expanded